# Custom Where expression

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, linq-to-nhibernate

I have simple inteface:

```
public interface IValid
{
   DateTime From {get;set;}
   DateTime? To {get;set;}
}
```

I want to have possibility to write simple expression like that:

```
dbContext.SomeClass
   .WhereValidOnDate(DateTime.Today)
   .Where(x=> ...more_expressions...)
   .ToList();
```

I think, that I need write some class with method signature:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereValidOnDate<TSource>(this
    IQueryable<TSource> source)
```

Inside that method, I need to do some simple data comparisons (hardcoded), like:

```
x => x.From<= DateTime.Today && (x.To == null || x.To <= DateTime.Today
```

I tried expression tree - works, but syntax is a little more messy:

```
dbContext.SomeClass
   .Where(IsValidExpression)
   .Cast<SomeClass>()
   .Where(x=> ...more_expressions...)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this signature and implemenation:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereValidOnDate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, DateTime other)
   where T : IValid
{
    return source.Where(x => x.From<= other && (x.To == null || x.To <= DateTime.Today));
}
```

Comment: I feel so generic anymore when programming in .NET; :D

Comment: And what to write inside that method? Thats the question :-)

Comment: I think the `DateTime.ToDay` is hardcoded as the OP said, so he may want to pass in another DateTime value in.

Comment: @VikciaR feel free to modify - this should at least get you the pattern you would need.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException Specified method is not supported. I think, that DateTime.Today is getting passed to sql generation and of course it fails to do so.

Comment: @VikciaR what method? that's important

Comment: I will play around with code you provided: removed DateTime.Today and added "where T : IValid", now it works. Thanks.